# sharepoint 2013 & Excel: we can't show these features in a browser: text queries

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I uploaded an Excel spreadsheet to Sharepoint 2013 & I'm getting this message "we can't show these features in a browser: text queries".  What text queries are they referring to?  I can't edit in the spreadsheet in the browser because of this

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was.

I followed the same steps as listed in [the "Most Helpful Reply"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/how-can-i-remove-text-queries-from-excel-documents/4d20d3a8-d6ba-441a-8830-0f7510d5d40b)  and the problem went away:

> I was having this issue also and came across this post. I followed the suggestion of deleting the info in the connections tab and the problem continued. However, after that if you click on the properties tab under the connections tab, there is a choice in there about saving the query data. I un-checked that and at the moment I believe this has solved the problem.